# Laravel "Class App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\MaterialController does not exist"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

estoy desarrollando un sitio con laravel pero me arroja el error del titulo al ejecutar el comando "php artisan route:list".
Tengo un controlador llamado MaterialController en la ruta: App\Http\Controllers\MaterialController.
El codigo de este controlador es el siguiente:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Material;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MaterialController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('material.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Material  $material
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Material $material)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Material  $material
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Material $material)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Material  $material
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Material $material)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Material  $material
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Material $material)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Y el codigo de web.php donde defino la ruta para rescatar las del controlador es el siguiente:

```
<?php
use App\Http\Controllers\MaterialController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('materiales',MaterialController::class);
```

el codigo que especificamente me da error es el que se encuentra en web.php: `Route::resource('materiales',MaterialController::class);`

Error detallado:

```
In Container.php line 752:

  Class App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\MaterialController does not exist
```

Como en el error se repite "App\Http\Controllers" intente borrandolo y utilizando solo el nombre del controlador "\MaterialController" pero donde debiese obtener "App\Http\Controllers\MaterialController" solo obtengo:

```
In web.php line 2:

  The use statement with non-compound name 'MaterialController' has no effect
```

alguien tiene alguna idea de como podria solucionar esto? la verdad estoy recien creando el proyecto por lo que no tengo muchos archivos creados manualmente y la verdad no tengo muchos conocimientos en laravel ya que estoy aprendiendolo, les agradeceria un monton su ayuda:(
La estructura de archivos es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Laravel usas?

Comment: @BetaM Uso laravel 4.2.4, revise donde se aloja el modelo de Material y se encuentra dentro de App, esta suelto, no dentro de Models, dentro de mi proyecto no existe esa carpeta, el proyecto lo cree con Composer 2.0.12, no se si tendra algo que ver con eso

Comment: ¿Laravel 4.2.4? Estás seguro?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Si, lo verifique con el cmd ´C:\Users\Felipe>laravel --version
Laravel Installer 4.2.4´

Comment: Si estás completamente seguro que es Laravel 4.2.4. Te diría que 1.- Actualizaras el proyecto en la medida de lo posible y 2.- Estas usando mal tus rutas. Tendría que ser de la siguiente manera: `Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController');`

Comment: Ahh.. esa es la versión del installer... Prueba `php artisan --version` o revisa el archivo `composer.json` en la clave `"laravel/framework"`.

Comment: @gaidyjg muchas gracias, ahi pude solucionar el error:D, la version es "Laravel Framework 5.5.50", habia buscado mal la version, sabes como podria actualizarla?

Comment: @FelipeGarcia tu versión de Laravel (**no del instalador**), de manera rápida la puedes ver el el *composer.json*, si es 5.x entonces los controladores se invocan como strings y no como lo tienes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la ruta estás usando la sintaxis que se implementó a partir de la versión 8.x de Laravel.

Si te fijas en el mensaje del error:

> “Class App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\MaterialController does not exist”

Está dos veces el namespace.

Esto es porque en versiones anteriores de Laravel, la clase [`RouteServiceProvider`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/a70a982cb19e2a623e59964a247562826c487f9e/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L17) contenía una propiedad `$namespace` con un valor `App\Http\Controllers`.
El valor de esta propiedad se usó para prefijar automáticamente las declaraciones de ruta del controlador y la generación de URL de ruta del controlador, como cuando se llama al helper `action`.

En Laravel 8, esta propiedad se establece en `null` de forma predeterminada. Esto permite que las declaraciones de ruta de su controlador utilicen la sintaxis estándar de PHP *callable syntax* (como la que muestras en la pregunta), que proporciona un mejor soporte para saltar a la clase de controlador en muchos IDE:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

// Usando la sintaxis PHP callable...
Route::get('/users', [UserController::class, 'index']);

// Usando la sintaxis string...
Route::get('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index');
```

Teniendo en cuenta que usas una versión anterior, la mejor opción es que uses la sintaxis de string en tu ruta, y Laravel se ocupará de prefijar el namespace a `App\Http\Controllers`:

```
Route::resource('materiales', 'MaterialController');
```

Ahora, si deseas usar la sintaxis PHP callable, puedes establecer el valor de la propiedad `$namespace` dentro de su `RouteServiceProvider` a `null` y actualizar los registros de ruta dentro del método `map` para usar la propiedad `$namespace`:

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    //...

    protected $namespace = null;

    //...
}
```

Referencia: [Prefijo automático del espacio de nombres del controlador](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#automatic-controller-namespace-prefixing).

**NOTA IMPORTANTE**:
Estás usando una versión que ya no cuenta con soporte a la fecha: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/releases#support-policy .
Lo mejor es que actualices a una versión actual que cuente con soporte.  Puedes seguir las guías de actualización (típicamente se actualiza a la versión inmediata superior, por lo que tendrás que ir paso a paso):
[Upgrading To 5.6.0 From 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade#upgrade-5.6.0).
[Upgrading To 5.7.0 From 5.6](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade#upgrade-5.7.0).
y así hasta llegar a la actual.

Comment: solucionadisimo el problema, se agradece, ya que tenia el proyecto casi nuevo cree otro con el comando `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel nombre_proyecto` y se creo con laravel actualizado al `8.36.2`, por si a alguien le llega a servir